# bat file to read one line at a time and execute a command and then move to next line

Tags: file, loops, vbscript, batch-file

im writing a bat file and i need it to read from a txt file one line at a time and execute a command each time and then move to the next line and execute that same command again. So basically I will have a text file with 30 ip addresses in it, then i want the bat to read the first one, execute the command on it, write the output to a seperate txt file and then move to line 2, execute the command and then write the output to a txt file, then line 3 and so forth, could anyone help me with this? I dont mind if you want me to use vbscript but then please explain clearly as i dont understand vbscript very well :(

Please I'm desperate I'm intergrating it with another tool in order to run an audit i'm doing and I need help

Comment: Use FOR /F to read your file one line at a time. Type `HELP FOR` from the command line for more info. Use standard redirection to write output to a file `command >file`. See how far you can get and post your code with updated question if you get stuck. Note that FOR variables are accessed using double percents within a batch file, as in `%%A`

Answer (score 5):

You don't need vbscript for such a simple task, if ip.txt is the file with your ip-adresses in then in your .bat or .cmd put

```
echo off
::to write the result to separate files
for /f %%a in (ip.txt) do ping -n 1 %%a>%%a.txt

::to write the result to one file
for /f %%a in (ip.txt) do ping -n 1 %%a>>output.txt
```

replace the %% by % if you give the commands at the console

Comment: given that your code is structured as a batch file with echo off at the top, you probably should use %%a in the code and change your note at the bottom accordingly :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using `FOR` to try `slmgr /ipk` on a file of keys:

```
@echo off
echo Proccessing keys...
echo ============================================================================
for /f %%a in (%1) do slmgr /ipk %%a
echo ============================================================================
echo Done proccessing keys.
pause
```

It can be used if you need to try a lot of keys at once.